# Appending a row to a dataframe while reading from multiple csv files in R

Tags: r, csv, dataframe

I'm reading from multiple csv files in a loop, and performing some calculations on each file's data, and then I wish to add that new row to a data frame:

```
for (i in csvFiles) {
    fileToBeRead<-paste(directory, i, sep="/")

    dataframe<-read.csv(paste(fileToBeRead, "csv", sep="."))
    file <- i
    recordsOK <- sum(complete.cases(dataframe))

    record.data <- data.frame(monitorID, recordsOK)
}
```

So, I want to add file and recordsOK as a new row to the data frame. This just overwrites data frame every time, so I'd end up with the data from the latest csv file. How can I do this while preserving the data from the last iteration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building a data.frame one row at a time is almost always the wrong way to do it. Here'a more R-like solution

```
OKcount<-sapply(csvFiles, function(i) {
    fileToBeRead<-paste(directory, i, sep="/")

    dataframe<-read.csv(paste(fileToBeRead, "csv", sep="."))
    sum(complete.cases(dataframe))
})

record.data <- data.frame(monitorID=seq_along(csvFiles), recordsOK=OKcount)
```

The main idea is that you generally build your data column-wise, not row-wise, and then bundle it together in a data.frame when you're all done. Because R has so many vectorized operations, this is usually pretty easy.

But if you really want to add rows to a data.frame, you can `rbind` (row bind) additional rows in. So instead of overwriting `record.data` each time, you would do

```
record.data <- rbind(record.data, data.frame(monitorID, recordsOK)
```

But that means you will need to define `record.data` outside of your loop and initialize it with the correct column names and data types since only matching data.frames can be combined. You can initialize it with

```
record.data <- data.frame(monitorID=numeric(), recordsOK=numeric())
```